# Does RAILS have GROUP BY...WITH ROLLUP query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, group-by

**GROUP BY... WITH ROLLUP** is a cool feature in sql.

Does Rails support ROLLUP ?

How can I write the query like,

```
.group('column1, column2,....')
```

Comment: No ActiveRecord doesn't have ROLLUP. https://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=1935

Comment: @Mahesh is there any alternate way to get the total of subgroups? I couldn't think of any.

Comment: You can write a sql query by using find_by_sql ref:- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html

Answer (score 0):

I normally use it like

```
@rollup = People.select(:occupation, :state, 'COUNT(`state`) as cnt')
             .group(:occupation, 'state WITH ROLLUP')
             .to_a.map(&:attributes)
```

then in my view use @rollup.first["state"] etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the RollUp clause in the group method of `ruby`. Let take an example, we have sql query like

```
SELECT *
FROM Lead
GROUP BY ROLLUP(LeadSource)
```

In rails we can map this query like:

```
Lead.group("lead_source with rollup")
```

Comment: Its seem to be syntax error. so can you please share the ROR code for db query