# How to use ROLLUP operator in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am making a mutli-series line-graph and I want to have a series for the data  overall. At first, I thought I would need two queries to retrieve the data: one query for overall, and one query for the data sorted by groups. But then I learned MySQL has this functionality built in through an operator called ROLLUP that you can add to your GROUP BY clause. Unfortunately, after lots of googling, I couldn't find any working examples. Does this functionality exist in ActiveRecord 4.2? If so, how can I use it?

Note that my query averages the data before the DB returns it so I cannot simply run one query and have my app run more computations on the result to get the overall value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, it seems ActiveRecord simply does not support the ROLLUP operator. [Does RAILS have GROUP BY...WITH ROLLUP query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007596/does-rails-have-group-by-with-rollup-query) offered a solution but it didn't work for me nor my coworkers.